# Query returns list based on order by each field (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, ecto

I want with just one query (SQl) in a table, that has multi "order by" of many fields.

I want with each "order by" of each field the query to return individual list results based on data in the table

ex:

```
name c1 c2
"a" 1   2
"b" 3   4
"c" 2   1
"d" 3   1
"e" 1   4
"f" 3   4
"g" 5   2
"h" 4   4
```

i want with one query to return 1 list based on order by "c1" and "c2" (asc) like below:

```
"a" 1   2 --> order asc by c1
"e" 1   4
"c" 2   1
"b" 3   4
"d" 3   1
"f" 3   4
"h" 4   4
"g" 5   2
----------

"c" 2   1 ---> order asc by c2
"d" 3   1
"a" 1   2
"g" 5   2
"b" 3   4
"e" 1   4
"f" 3   4
"h" 4   4
```

Comment: Why do you want this to be a single query?

Comment: because i just want to minimum the number of times query to database by just one instead of 2 like example above

Comment: I'm trying to write a single query that will return these results, but just FYI anything I come up with will have to query the same table twice, if we're talking about pure SQL. So you're not saving anything in terms of performance. The only way around this would be to query the db once, then make whatever transformations you want in your code.

Comment: i just have a separate data server, so i think that it'll take time to connect and query if i create many individual query, instead i can create all with just one query if i can, thanks for your comment!

Comment: IMO, you can save time by handling this logic in your code, not SQL.

Comment: sorry, unfortunately for me, my mentor does not want me to handle by code, he want me think about just by query and return all of that, this is my challenge for now :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (values ('col1'), ('col2')) v(which)
order by v.which,
         (case when which = 'col1' then col1 end) asc,
         (case when which = 'col2' then col2 end) asc;
```

Note that two separate queries might be *faster* for two reasons:

1. Sorting scales as O(n * ln(n)), which means that doubling the data being sorted more than doubles the time needed to sort.
2. If you have indexes on `col1` and/or `col2`, then the index can be used for the sorting.  That is not possible with the more complex keys.

Comment: This seems like the correct answer, it gives me (almost) the same result as the one in the description. Only difference is some rows which have same c2 when ordering by c1 (and vice versa) have switched places. The result is still correct based on the ordering requested, however.

Comment: @IraklisGkougkousis . . . You can add additional `order by` keys or just adjust the logic.  This may do what you want:  `order by v.which, (case when which = 'col1' then col1 end) asc, col2 asc, col1`.

Comment: yes! thank you very much! :), this is what i want, i'll also think about the trade off more to optimize my query, but your answer just solve my problem